# Inserting an array into different rows in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm having an issue inserting an array into my database. When i tried implode, it all inserted all the arrays into one row. What i intend to achieve is to insert a single array into different rows.
In the array i have fields such as bag,shoes,cloths and i wish to insert into one table but different rows.

```
$subjectArray[] =$_POST['subject'];
$all_subjects_to_insert = array();
foreach ($subjectArray as $p){
    if(!empty($p)) $all_subjects_to_insert = $p;      
}
$all_subjects_to_insert = array_unique($all_subjects_to_insert);
$final = implode(',',$all_subjects_to_insert);
$query = "INSERT INTO #__sch_subject (subject) VALUES ('$final')";
```

I'll appreciate any help i get. Thanks.

Comment: is `$all_subjects_to_insert`  multidimensional array ?

Comment: `$all_subjects_to_insert = $p;` should be `$all_subjects_to_insert[] = $p;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Its now working. The separator for the implode function was incorrect. Here is the working code

```
$subjectArray[] =$_POST['subject'];
$all_subjects_to_insert = array();
foreach ($subjectArray as $p){
    if(!empty($p)) $all_subjects_to_insert = $p;      
}
$all_subjects_to_insert = array_unique($all_subjects_to_insert);
$inserted_values = implode("'),('",$all_subjects_to_insert);
print_r($finalvalues);
$query = "INSERT INTO #__sch_subject (subject) VALUES ('$inserted_values')";
```

With the separator the insert command looks like this

```
$query ="INSERT INTO #__sch_subject (Subject) VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')";
```

Thanks for the help. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

if `$all_subjects_to_insert` is multidimensional array then what you are looking for is

```
foreach($all_subjects_to_insert as $value)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO #__sch_subject (subject) VALUES ('{$value}')";
    mysql_query($query);
 }
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: It's not a multidimensional array

Comment: Show us structure of your array

Comment: here is the structure of the array Array ( [0] => Biology [1] => chemistry [2] => physics [3] => english [4] => spanish [5] => arabic [6] => zulu [7] => indian [8] => french )

Comment: Okay now do you want to do .. insert `biology` in one row `chemistry` in other row like this ?

Comment: it only inserted the last array while leaving others out

Comment: @IfeoluwapoOjikutu are you using mysqli_query() with loop to execute the query ?

Comment: Thanks, its now working. Posted the working code below. I really appreciate all the explanation and help. I'm grateful.

Comment: @IfeoluwapoOjikutu for no reasons ..glad to help you ... I didnt realized that you are trying to make this syntax